# AppleScript functionality for opening System Preferences panes seems to have changed in Ventura

Tags: applescript, ventura

The following applescript works fine in Monterey but not Ventura, does anyone know why?

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.general"
    delay 1
end tell
```

Comment: Maybe because Apple changed "System Preferences" extensively and it is now "System Settings?"

Comment: I’ve slightly changed the title to mention the question is asking specifically about system preferences, hope that’s ok

Comment: @grg no problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme `x-apple.systempreferences` works in Ventura with `.extension`s.

```
do shell script "open x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Appearance-Settings.extension"
```

A list of available options is available at https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2022/10/25/opening-macos-venturas-system-settings-to-desired-locations-via-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help you?

```
do shell script "open -b com.apple.systempreferences"

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until static text 1 of UI element 1 of row 14 of ¬
        outline 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of ¬
        group 1 of window "Appearance" of process "System Settings" exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    key code 126 -- up arrow key
end tell
```